# How to test a nested form with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm having an issue figuring out how to do something with rspec, and I'm not sure how I'd go about it. I already looked for examples and there doesn't seem to be any so I was wondering if someone could help me.

Here's basically what I'm attempting to do:

```
def new 
   @survey = Survey.new
   5.times{survey.questions.build}
end
```

and this is my test:

```
it "creates a new survey object with a list of questions to be inserted" do
    survey = Survey.create! valid_attributes
    get :new 
    expect(assigns(:survey)).to be_a_new(Survey)
end
```

It works fine to check that a new survey was created, but how to do I verify that those five questions are also in that survey?

Comment: `expect(assigns(:survey).questions.size).to eq 5`

Comment: thanks for the help.